# How can I set the className of an element I pass in as an argument?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, jsx

I'm creating a `sidebar` component. The sidebar component has sidebar segment components, named `sidebaricon`s. The `sidebaricon` component takes in 3 parameters: the icon, the text and the type (location: top, bottom or middle - for alignment purposes only).

The problem lies in the icon. I need to set the `className` of this icon, which is an argument. But I don't know how to do this and I can't find any solutions online (maybe I searched poorly?).  The reason why I need to set the `className` is for creating a `group` with `Tailwind` for a hover interaction. Bear in mind, the code below WORKS but the docs say that it's a method that shouldn't be used.

The `sidebaricon` component:

```
const typeToMargin = {
        top: 'align-baseline',
        middle: 'align-baseline',
        bottom: 'mt-auto',
    };


const SideBarIcon = ({icon, text, type}) => (

        <div className={`${typeToMargin[type]} select-none h-auto ml-[2.314814815vh] flex flex-row items-center group/sidebaricon`}>
            
            {React.cloneElement(icon, { className: 'fill-main-gray group-hover/sidebaricon:fill-off-white transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200' })}
            {<h1 className='ml-[2.314814815vh] font-montserrat font-extralight text-main-gray whitespace-nowrap text-2xl md:leading-none group-hover/sidebaricon:text-off-white transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200'>{text}</h1>}
        </div>
);
```

Example svg component to be passed as an icon. Created using `svg-to-react-cli`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function SettingsIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg width={22} height={21} viewBox="0 0 22 21" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" {...props}>
      <path d="M10.9975 5.70417C10.111 5.70417 9.24452 5.96703 8.50747 6.45951C7.77043 6.95199 7.19597 7.65197 6.85675 8.47093C6.51752 9.28989 6.42876 10.191 6.6017 11.0605C6.77463 11.9299 7.20149 12.7285 7.8283 13.3553C8.45511 13.9821 9.25371 14.4089 10.1231 14.5819C10.9925 14.7548 11.8937 14.666 12.7126 14.3268C13.5316 13.9876 14.2316 13.4131 14.7241 12.6761C15.2165 11.939 15.4794 11.0725 15.4794 10.1861C15.478 8.99782 15.0054 7.85861 14.1652 7.01838C13.325 6.17815 12.1857 5.70552 10.9975 5.70417ZM10.9975 13.8531C10.2722 13.8531 9.56324 13.638 8.9602 13.2351C8.35717 12.8322 7.88715 12.2594 7.60961 11.5894C7.33206 10.9193 7.25944 10.182 7.40093 9.47068C7.54243 8.75935 7.89167 8.10595 8.40452 7.59311C8.91736 7.08027 9.57076 6.73102 10.2821 6.58952C10.9934 6.44803 11.7307 6.52065 12.4008 6.7982C13.0709 7.07575 13.6436 7.54576 14.0465 8.14879C14.4494 8.75183 14.6645 9.46081 14.6645 10.1861C14.6645 11.1586 14.2782 12.0914 13.5905 12.779C12.9028 13.4667 11.97 13.8531 10.9975 13.8531ZM21.7948 8.14885C21.7828 8.09097 21.7584 8.0364 21.7232 7.98891C21.688 7.94142 21.643 7.90215 21.5911 7.87382L18.4446 6.08106C18.4127 6.02537 18.3787 5.97037 18.3427 5.91604L18.3417 2.36311C18.3413 2.30472 18.3281 2.24713 18.3031 2.19435C18.2781 2.14157 18.2419 2.09488 18.1971 2.05753C17.1344 1.15794 15.9103 0.468655 14.5901 0.0264096C14.5363 0.00808938 14.4792 0.00125295 14.4225 0.00634064C14.3658 0.0114283 14.3109 0.0283273 14.2611 0.0559493L11.0993 1.82019H10.8956L7.73792 0.0518749C7.68825 0.0240858 7.63332 0.00700942 7.57665 0.00174618C7.51998 -0.00351706 7.46284 0.0031495 7.40891 0.0213164C6.08921 0.466205 4.86594 1.15751 3.80403 2.05855C3.75963 2.09626 3.72384 2.14305 3.69907 2.19576C3.67429 2.24848 3.66111 2.30589 3.6604 2.36413L3.6441 5.9191L3.54224 6.08412L0.393702 7.87382C0.343727 7.90325 0.300611 7.94301 0.267235 7.99044C0.233859 8.03786 0.210993 8.09187 0.200165 8.14885C-0.0667217 9.49389 -0.0667217 10.8783 0.200165 12.2233C0.211572 12.2807 0.235218 12.335 0.269495 12.3825C0.303771 12.4299 0.347872 12.4695 0.398795 12.4983L3.5453 14.2911C3.57721 14.3475 3.61117 14.4025 3.64716 14.4561L3.65938 18.008C3.65981 18.0664 3.67297 18.124 3.69796 18.1768C3.72294 18.2296 3.75914 18.2763 3.80403 18.3136C4.86669 19.2132 6.09074 19.9025 7.41094 20.3447C7.46481 20.363 7.52191 20.3699 7.57858 20.3648C7.63524 20.3597 7.69022 20.3428 7.73996 20.3152L10.8956 18.552H11.0993L14.2571 20.3203C14.3067 20.3481 14.3617 20.3651 14.4183 20.3704C14.475 20.3757 14.5321 20.369 14.5861 20.3508C15.9058 19.906 17.129 19.2146 18.1909 18.3136C18.2353 18.2759 18.2711 18.2291 18.2959 18.1764C18.3207 18.1237 18.3339 18.0663 18.3346 18.008L18.3509 14.4531L18.4527 14.288L21.6013 12.4983C21.6533 12.4699 21.6984 12.4305 21.7336 12.3828C21.7688 12.3351 21.7932 12.2803 21.805 12.2223C22.0684 10.8769 22.0649 9.49289 21.7948 8.14885ZM21.0329 11.8841L17.9546 13.6331C17.8901 13.67 17.8369 13.7239 17.8008 13.7889C17.7387 13.8999 17.6735 14.01 17.6063 14.119C17.5657 14.1829 17.5441 14.2571 17.5441 14.3329L17.5278 17.8114C16.6249 18.5502 15.6015 19.1281 14.5025 19.5197L11.406 17.788C11.3437 17.7534 11.2735 17.7355 11.2022 17.7361H10.8101C10.7371 17.7348 10.6651 17.7527 10.6012 17.788L7.49956 19.5197C6.39872 19.1292 5.37303 18.5528 4.46714 17.8155L4.45492 14.34C4.45506 14.2639 4.4335 14.1893 4.39279 14.1251C4.32556 14.0232 4.26037 13.9071 4.19823 13.7961C4.16214 13.731 4.10895 13.6771 4.04442 13.6402L0.963108 11.8851C0.762443 10.762 0.762443 9.61219 0.963108 8.48907L4.04035 6.73908C4.10488 6.70214 4.15807 6.64825 4.19416 6.58324C4.25629 6.47221 4.32148 6.3622 4.38871 6.25422C4.42907 6.18978 4.4506 6.11533 4.45085 6.0393L4.46714 2.56072C5.37008 1.82194 6.39345 1.2441 7.49243 0.852506L10.589 2.58415C10.6529 2.61941 10.7249 2.63732 10.7978 2.6361H11.189C11.262 2.63781 11.3341 2.61987 11.3978 2.58415L14.4995 0.852506C15.5989 1.24333 16.6232 1.81973 17.5278 2.55665L17.5401 6.03217C17.5399 6.10826 17.5615 6.18281 17.6022 6.24709C17.6694 6.34895 17.7346 6.46508 17.7967 6.57611C17.8328 6.64112 17.886 6.69501 17.9506 6.73195L21.0319 8.48703C21.2335 9.60998 21.2346 10.7598 21.0349 11.8831L21.0329 11.8841Z" />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

I tried using `React.CloneElement` as seen above but the docs say that this is a rarely used feature. This also feels like it could have implications for memory usage since although the parameter isn't actually rendered (but cloned, then rendered), it theoretically should still use up space.

NB: I'm not great at React but it's pretty fun to use. If you see any other glaring issues with my code, please tell me and if possible, show me how to fix it. This is also my first post on stack-overflow, so if you see anything in my post that could be better, let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider passing the icon component as a prop to `SideBarIcon`. This would be similar to what you already have, but without the `React.cloneElement()` call:

```js
const typeToMargin = {
  top: "align-baseline",
  middle: "align-baseline",
  bottom: "mt-auto",
};

const SideBarIcon = ({ Icon, text, type }) => (
  <div
    className={`${typeToMargin[type]} select-none h-auto ml-[2.314814815vh] flex flex-row items-center group/sidebaricon`}
  >
    <Icon className="fill-main-gray group-hover/sidebaricon:fill-off-white transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200" />
    <h1 className="ml-[2.314814815vh] font-montserrat font-extralight text-main-gray whitespace-nowrap text-2xl md:leading-none group-hover/sidebaricon:text-off-white transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200">
      {text}
    </h1>
  </div>
);

function SettingsIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      width={22}
      height={21}
      viewBox="0 0 22 21"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      {...props}
    >
      <path d="M10.9975 5.70417C10.111 5.70417 9.24452 5.96703 8.50747 6.45951C7.77043 6.95199 7.19597 7.65197 6.85675 8.47093C6.51752 9.28989 6.42876 10.191 6.6017 11.0605C6.77463 11.9299 7.20149 12.7285 7.8283 13.3553C8.45511 13.9821 9.25371 14.4089 10.1231 14.5819C10.9925 14.7548 11.8937 14.666 12.7126 14.3268C13.5316 13.9876 14.2316 13.4131 14.7241 12.6761C15.2165 11.939 15.4794 11.0725 15.4794 10.1861C15.478 8.99782 15.0054 7.85861 14.1652 7.01838C13.325 6.17815 12.1857 5.70552 10.9975 5.70417ZM10.9975 13.8531C10.2722 13.8531 9.56324 13.638 8.9602 13.2351C8.35717 12.8322 7.88715 12.2594 7.60961 11.5894C7.33206 10.9193 7.25944 10.182 7.40093 9.47068C7.54243 8.75935 7.89167 8.10595 8.40452 7.59311C8.91736 7.08027 9.57076 6.73102 10.2821 6.58952C10.9934 6.44803 11.7307 6.52065 12.4008 6.7982C13.0709 7.07575 13.6436 7.54576 14.0465 8.14879C14.4494 8.75183 14.6645 9.46081 14.6645 10.1861C14.6645 11.1586 14.2782 12.0914 13.5905 12.779C12.9028 13.4667 11.97 13.8531 10.9975 13.8531ZM21.7948 8.14885C21.7828 8.09097 21.7584 8.0364 21.7232 7.98891C21.688 7.94142 21.643 7.90215 21.5911 7.87382L18.4446 6.08106C18.4127 6.02537 18.3787 5.97037 18.3427 5.91604L18.3417 2.36311C18.3413 2.30472 18.3281 2.24713 18.3031 2.19435C18.2781 2.14157 18.2419 2.09488 18.1971 2.05753C17.1344 1.15794 15.9103 0.468655 14.5901 0.0264096C14.5363 0.00808938 14.4792 0.00125295 14.4225 0.00634064C14.3658 0.0114283 14.3109 0.0283273 14.2611 0.0559493L11.0993 1.82019H10.8956L7.73792 0.0518749C7.68825 0.0240858 7.63332 0.00700942 7.57665 0.00174618C7.51998 -0.00351706 7.46284 0.0031495 7.40891 0.0213164C6.08921 0.466205 4.86594 1.15751 3.80403 2.05855C3.75963 2.09626 3.72384 2.14305 3.69907 2.19576C3.67429 2.24848 3.66111 2.30589 3.6604 2.36413L3.6441 5.9191L3.54224 6.08412L0.393702 7.87382C0.343727 7.90325 0.300611 7.94301 0.267235 7.99044C0.233859 8.03786 0.210993 8.09187 0.200165 8.14885C-0.0667217 9.49389 -0.0667217 10.8783 0.200165 12.2233C0.211572 12.2807 0.235218 12.335 0.269495 12.3825C0.303771 12.4299 0.347872 12.4695 0.398795 12.4983L3.5453 14.2911C3.57721 14.3475 3.61117 14.4025 3.64716 14.4561L3.65938 18.008C3.65981 18.0664 3.67297 18.124 3.69796 18.1768C3.72294 18.2296 3.75914 18.2763 3.80403 18.3136C4.86669 19.2132 6.09074 19.9025 7.41094 20.3447C7.46481 20.363 7.52191 20.3699 7.57858 20.3648C7.63524 20.3597 7.69022 20.3428 7.73996 20.3152L10.8956 18.552H11.0993L14.2571 20.3203C14.3067 20.3481 14.3617 20.3651 14.4183 20.3704C14.475 20.3757 14.5321 20.369 14.5861 20.3508C15.9058 19.906 17.129 19.2146 18.1909 18.3136C18.2353 18.2759 18.2711 18.2291 18.2959 18.1764C18.3207 18.1237 18.3339 18.0663 18.3346 18.008L18.3509 14.4531L18.4527 14.288L21.6013 12.4983C21.6533 12.4699 21.6984 12.4305 21.7336 12.3828C21.7688 12.3351 21.7932 12.2803 21.805 12.2223C22.0684 10.8769 22.0649 9.49289 21.7948 8.14885ZM21.0329 11.8841L17.9546 13.6331C17.8901 13.67 17.8369 13.7239 17.8008 13.7889C17.7387 13.8999 17.6735 14.01 17.6063 14.119C17.5657 14.1829 17.5441 14.2571 17.5441 14.3329L17.5278 17.8114C16.6249 18.5502 15.6015 19.1281 14.5025 19.5197L11.406 17.788C11.3437 17.7534 11.2735 17.7355 11.2022 17.7361H10.8101C10.7371 17.7348 10.6651 17.7527 10.6012 17.788L7.49956 19.5197C6.39872 19.1292 5.37303 18.5528 4.46714 17.8155L4.45492 14.34C4.45506 14.2639 4.4335 14.1893 4.39279 14.1251C4.32556 14.0232 4.26037 13.9071 4.19823 13.7961C4.16214 13.731 4.10895 13.6771 4.04442 13.6402L0.963108 11.8851C0.762443 10.762 0.762443 9.61219 0.963108 8.48907L4.04035 6.73908C4.10488 6.70214 4.15807 6.64825 4.19416 6.58324C4.25629 6.47221 4.32148 6.3622 4.38871 6.25422C4.42907 6.18978 4.4506 6.11533 4.45085 6.0393L4.46714 2.56072C5.37008 1.82194 6.39345 1.2441 7.49243 0.852506L10.589 2.58415C10.6529 2.61941 10.7249 2.63732 10.7978 2.6361H11.189C11.262 2.63781 11.3341 2.61987 11.3978 2.58415L14.4995 0.852506C15.5989 1.24333 16.6232 1.81973 17.5278 2.55665L17.5401 6.03217C17.5399 6.10826 17.5615 6.18281 17.6022 6.24709C17.6694 6.34895 17.7346 6.46508 17.7967 6.57611C17.8328 6.64112 17.886 6.69501 17.9506 6.73195L21.0319 8.48703C21.2335 9.60998 21.2346 10.7598 21.0349 11.8831L21.0329 11.8841Z" />
    </svg>
  );
}

function Sidebar() {
  return <SideBarIcon Icon={SettingsIcon} text="Foo" type="top" />;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(<Sidebar />);

tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'main-gray': 'gray',
        'off-white': 'beige',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! Works like a charm. I did try this before but I reckon the compiler wasn't happy with me using camelCase instead of PascalCase (whoops!)